# Setting correct UTM zone

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, utm

I am using QGIS for mapping a series of buildings, I got the UTM coordinates from Google Maps and imported them as a delimited text layer.

However when I search for the UTM Zone that I need it doesn't appear I need `14Q` and the only one I can get is `14N`.

Answer (score 6):

No, you need 14N (N is for Northern Hemisphere). The "Q" is just a [latitude band designation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Latitude_bands).

> ## Latitude bands
>
> Latitude bands are not a part of UTM, but rather a part of the military grid reference system (MGRS). They are however sometimes used.
>
> **Latitude bands**
>
> Each zone is segmented into 20 latitude bands. Each latitude band is 8 degrees high, and is lettered starting from "C" at 80°S, increasing up the English alphabet until "X", omitting the letters "I" and "O" (because of their similarity to the numerals one and zero). The last latitude band, "X", is extended an extra 4 degrees, so it ends at 84°N latitude, thus covering the northernmost land on Earth.